# How to print log in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-log, android-studio-4.2

I want to print some logs for debug reason, it seems the print and Timber are all not work with compose, what's the alternative choice?

Comment: I believe this question is not very useful since it can make people think that logging in Jetpack Compose is different than logging anywhere else.

Comment: You can check out this library to log right on your phone -> https://github.com/girish3/Vlog

Comment: @Victor Ramos - The question is actually interesting because Compose provide UI interaction in Android studio itself. If there is a way to print states or layout values without log from phone would be great

Comment: @VitorRamos writing `Log.i(TAG, String)` actually crashes my app, so logging obviously DOESN'T work, or why would he write a question otherwise

Answer (score 7):

`Timber` or `Log` or `println` all work fine in Compose, If Timber is not worked, then check did you initialize `Timber`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize Timber as

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   Timber.plant(DebugTree)
}
```

inside `Application::onCreate() method`

Comment: Thx. To be exact nowadays: `Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())`.